# C# Removing a Value from a list

Tags: c#

The following code is just been used as an example but i can't seem to get it to work. Getting the error 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Remove
 and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of 'System.Array' could be found.

```
int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = a.Remove(4)
```

The examples that ive seen removes the 4 from the list meaning a then = [1,2,3,5]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: It is not a list that you are using, it is an array. These are different things

Comment: I recommend using a `List<int>`, `Array` is for fixed elements, if you need to remove/add use `List`. That said, your question is a duplicate, if you really want to remove items from an array, use the duplicate question link above your question.

Comment: you should you  
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
a.Remove(4);